# iOs style screen transition in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Does someone know how to achieve an iOs like screen transition in flutter. This is a sliding from right to left with a parallax effect done with the previous screen.
I tried to use CupertinoPageRoute, it changes nothing on iOs and this is definitely not an iOs page transition.

Comment: What do you mean by *it changes nothing on iOs*?

Comment: can you edit youe question with CupertinoPageRoutet code?

Comment: @Riwen On iOs the transition remains the same, the screen B slide in from right to left and cover the screen A, but there is no animation of the screen A, who is normally also sliding to the left, with a different speed.